# Writing an mp4 file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, mp4

I am trying to figure out how to take a string that is the file contents of a mp4 file and write a properly formatted mp4 file. Currently I am just throwing the string into a file and slapping a .mp4 extension on it, but this resulting file cannot be played by any video players (I am assuming because of all the missing meta data).

```
def write_mp4(mp4_string)
  file = File.new('movie.mp4', 'w')
  file.puts(mp4_string)
  file.close
end
```

For context, I am doing this in a Ruby on Rails application, not sure if that changes anything. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `"wb"` mode, which will suppress EOL conversions and set the encoding properly
- Use `write`, not `puts`, as the latter inserts an extra EOL
- You could use a shortcut: `File.write('movie.mp4', mp4_string, mode: 'wb')` - or even `File.binwrite('movie.mp4', mp4_string)`.

Of course, make sure the string actually contains a correct file before - for example, if `mp4_string.encoding` doesn't return `#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`, you probably done goofed somewhere before the writing step, too :)